# Lua table constructor values as multi-value-return function calls

Tags: lua, lua-table

Using Lua (5.1) I would like to fill the table with functions which return several values. Unfortunately, due to Lua specification such function call will only be expanded for the last one.

```
function get2() return 1, 2 end
local t = { get2(), get2() }
for _,v in pairs(t) do print(v) end
```

Returns: `1, 1, 2`

Is there any way of doing this besides

```
table = {}; 
res1, res2 = get2(); 
table[#table + 1] = res1; 
table[#table + 1] = res2
```

or some other convoluted technique?

Comment: Related mailing list thread: http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2012-10/msg00307.html

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no direct way to do this.

But you can simplify the code with a helper function.

```
function get2() return 1, 2 end

function appendMultiple(t, ...)
  for i=1, select('#', ...) do
    t[#t+1] = select(i, ...)
  end
end

local t = { }
appendMultiple(t, get2())
appendMultiple(t, get2())

for _,v in pairs(t) do print(v) end
--> 1  2  1  2
```

Comment: I hoped there is a better way to do it. Thanks, nevertheless.